# Auto create data modules

Tags: forms, firemonkey, autocreate

I have set `MyDataModule` in the `Forms` section of the `Project -> Options`, under the `Auto create` panel, in top of the main form, so at run time, `MyDataModule` should be created and its constructor should be fired.

However, when running the application, the `MyDataModule` constructor is not fired.

Why `MyDataModule` constructor is not fired?

Any help will be appreciated.